# while connect got an error

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2017 and I have a hard time connecting to it because of this error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP=VO0MRKA.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

I tried many solutions, but still can't connect.

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Your machine has an equal sign in the host name? I don't think that is a valid name.

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server 2017 did you install (Express? Web? Standard? Developer?) And when you installed - did you explicitly specify an **instance name** or did you just use the recommended defaults?

Comment: What do you have here: HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/Instance Names/SQL and here: HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/ in the registry on your computer?

Comment: You can use Process Explorer from sysinternals. Use the "Find -> Find Handle or DLL..." option and enter the pattern "\Device\NamedPipe\". It will show you which processes have which pipes open.

Comment: Characters that cannot be used in Windows computer names: ` ~ ! @ # $ ^ & * ( ) = + { } [ ] \ | ; : ' " , < > / ?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your computer name is legal (VO0MRKA), then try this...

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager. See what's enabled for your SQL Server: Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP. I would start with just having Shared Memory enabled. See what's enabled for you SQL client under SQL Native Client look for Client Protocols. Make sure that only Shared Memory is enabled. Restart SQL Server using this same application under SQL Server Services.

You should now be able to make shared memory connections.

How to do a UDL test...
Create a new file on your desktop and change the extension to UDL. Double click the file to launch Data Link Properties...

Provider tab: select SQL Server Native Client x.x
Connection tab: 
 - input your SQL Server name: VO0MRKA
 - input your security creds in the log on info area
Now see if you can get a list of DB names from "Select the database:" drop down.